# When the data is all zeros, how can I expand y range from 0.3 (which is the default value) to 10?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

In the MPAndroidChart line chart, I have different kinds of data. When the data is all 0s, I would like to expand y range from 0.3 (which is the default value) to 10. However, when I use `y.setAxisMaxValue(20f)`, `y.setAxisMinValue(-20f)` kinds of codes, it stays in the same range all the time. For instance, the normal data [is like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vbl9p.png)  but the data with all zeros [like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrUT7.png). Then I use set axis min max values functions, the data with all zeros becomes the data I wanted [as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPlRn.png). However, the normal data is gone to the somewhere I can't see [like this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDhhf.png)

What can I do about this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to continuously update Y-axis values in MPAndroidChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934301/how-to-continuously-update-y-axis-values-in-mpandroidchart) If you set the axis range manually once, you must set it all the time. You might also try using `setAutoScaleMinMaxEnabled` to reset auto scaling, but I didn't try.

Comment: Yes I am using auto update for normal data which is perfect but I need to change the range of y axis when the data is full with zeros.

Comment: Then check your data points and set the axis accordingly when updating.